# looking for a 90's fantasy I read it in trade paperback woman falls in love with leader of rebellion (who is actually a prince)

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

-it was a Fantasy book trade size paperback, I remember it being a light-colored cover, like pink, peach, or light yellow or light green. It had a symbol on the front like a labyrinth I think).
Plot from what I remember:

A young woman works at an inn and falls in with a group of soldiers who stop at the inn. They are going to stop an uprising/rebellion that is being led by a charismatic leader.
As she travels with them, she also develops her magical powers (she calls on elemental-type creatures).

Once they get to the uprising, she goes undercover and starts to believe in the rebellion’s cause. The leader of the uprising is actually the prince of the kingdom who is trying to stop the uprising.

She falls in love with the prince. He gets captured and imprisoned in the dungeons of the main castle of the kingdom, she enters the prison and is able to rescue him. It’s setup for a sequel.
Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: I think I might have read this. Is the girl a member of some persecuted minority (I think maybe magic users were persecuted) and the job at the inn is the only work she's allowed to do? I think when the soldiers turn up she is scrubbing the doorstep of the inn.